# Opposite of heat?

Tags: antonyms

What is the opposite of **heat**?

Hot>Cold

Hotness>Coldness

But Heat>?

I think as **Heat** actually means *heat energy*, it should not or does not have an opposite. Is this right?

Comment: What's the opposite of *"The cold is making me shiver"?* Is it *"The hot is making me sweat"?* Or should that be *"heat"*?

Comment: Are you looking for an antonym for the noun or verb version of "heat"?

Comment: @KristinaLopez what's an example of the verb form of heat?

Comment: I put it in an answer, @AmanThakkar

Comment: @Kristinlopez an example of the verb form of heat is "Heat the water to 100 degrees centigrade to boil it."

Comment: This is rather like asking what is the opposite of time.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I wanted to know if there was one

Comment: @Aman Thakkar \ I agree with your assessment that "heat" has no true antonym since its "opposite" would mean merely "a state in which there is no (or less) heat." Your conception of heat would seem cool to a person whose frame of reference is the level of heat in the sun.

Comment: You are right that, from a thermodynamic/physics standpoint, "heat" has no "opposite" -- the closest you get is "the absence of heat".  But for ordinary human perception the opposite is "cold" (adjective/noun) or "cool" (verb), as described in some of the answers.

Comment: @Hot Licks \ I have an official certificate which confirms my human ordinariness.

Answer (score 4):

***Hot*** (qua adjective) is the opposite of ***cold*** (qua adjective).

***Heat*** (qua noun) is the opposite of ***cold*** (qua noun).

Comment: So **cold** can be used in 2 forms...that clears it

Answer (score 2):

For the ***verb*** form of "heat", the opposite is "cool":

> "My soup is cold, I need to ***heat*** it."
>
> "My soup is actually gazpacho so don't heat it, ***cool*** it down!"

Comment: Heat just means the measure of thermal energy, cold is a description of relative temperature from the perspective of humans on Earth.

Comment: I guess **heat it** means to provide heat energy to it. **Cool it** means remove the heat energy then

Comment: Actually, in my example, heat means apply energy to raise the temperature of the soup, to cool means to lower the temperature of the soup via other means, both of which involve thermodynamics, though. (That's not my area of expertise so hopefully that explanation didn't sound totally ridiculous!) :-)

Comment: 20 years ago in a materials science laboratory, I used a "chill block" to regulate the temperature of a specimen.  So I "chilled" as a verb.

Comment: It's clear to me now, thanks. But may I know why someone would want to downvote my question?

Answer (score 2):

frigid        *adj.*   Lacking heat

frigidity               *noun*   Lack of heat

entropy          *noun*   Lack of available heat
                                           (physics/thermodynamics)

Comment: Hi, human. I upvote this answer. Please go ahead and post the link to the comment.

Answer (score 1):

We say of the weather, "This heat is unbearable" or "this cold is unbearable," so in at least some senses "cold" is the opposite of "heat."

Comment: It's whether you use it as a noun or adjective

Answer (score 0):

As a noun used for the weather as stated in the above answers its "cold."  If used to denote the energy of something there is no opposite.  If you ask whats the heat of the universe its close to 0 Kelvin and that's considered cold to humans on Earth.  We don't generally say "What's the cold of the universe?" for example.

Comment: Yes, I was only thinking on the 'energy' lines, because that's where I needed it at first. Now I've got it